# writing to a text file in java

Tags: java

I have the following function for writing to a file:

```
public void writeToFile(String data) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fstream = null;


    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(data);
        //Close the output stream
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fstream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What it does every time it is called it creates a new file and writes a new line. What I want to achieve is to check whether file exist. If not create a new file and write something, if exists then open the file and add a new line without erasing existing text. How to do that?

Comment: isFile() returns true if the file exists, and false if not.

Comment: Or save yourself some code: `com.google.common.io.Files.append(CharSequence, File, Charset)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your FileOutputStream constructor call to this:

```
fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

FileWriter takes in an additional parameter for appends, which specifies if you want to create a new file or append to an existing file

```
fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt", true);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Comment: +1, Can't understand why the other answer has more votes, this is a better answer, although the link might be better as http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

As there is a constructor in java's FileWriter class that can get an bool that idicates if the next "entry" is appended to the file, you should chage your

```
fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
```

to

```
fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt", true);
```

You can look up all those constructors in the java documentation:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html